# Ubuntu 14.04 for Dell Precision 7510

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, dell

I got a new Dell Precision 7510 workstation for work which shipped with a Windows 7 Professional installation. The Dell purchase page does give an option for pre-installed Ubuntu 14.04 SP1 but my group's admin missed out on this spec.

I need Ubuntu 14.04 for my research and was wondering if there is an official Canonical distribution for this hardware.

Thanks,
Abhishek

P.S.: I did install Ubuntu 14.04.2 on the system but it does not recognize the NVIDIA Quadro M2000M graphics hardware.

Comment: Did you try the proprietary driver?

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to install the proprietary driver for the graphics card.

To install it, open the Dash Menu on Ubuntu and type: Additional

Then you will see a program called "Additional Drivers".

Click on it, and a window will pop-up with any available drivers. If your graphics card is compatible with Ubuntu you will find it in the list of drivers in the program similar to this:[image]

Then you select the driver you want to install, (the program might prompt you to type in your administrative password), the program will install the driver, then you will be prompted to reboot the system in order for the driver to start working.

That's it! Just reboot and your graphics card will start working like a charm with it's proprietary driver.

Enjoy!